# Alpine.js: nested x-for in a table: how to wrap multiple elements without breaking the table?

Tags: alpine.js

I'm using Alpine.js v3 and I'm trying to create a table based on a `json`. However, the structure of my `json` makes me use nested `x-for` inside my `<table>`.

Knowing that `x-for` must contain only one root element, this causes problems for the display of my articles. With `<div>` this would not be a problem, but the particular structure of tables is creating an issue: it is impossible (?) to add a tag to my articles without breaking the table.

- I thought about wrapping everything with `<tr><td colspan="5"><tbody>` but even that break the table.
- Another solution was to nest `<table>` elements. If it do works, it breaks the alignment of the parents columns, plus copy/pasting the table to another editor also breaks.

Do you have any suggestion?

My json:

```json
{
  "articles": {
    "CHAPTER I": {
      "title": "GENERAL PROVISIONS",
      "articles": {
        "Article 1": {
          "title": "Subject matter",
          "paragraphs": {
            "p_1": "This Regulation lays down:",
            "(a)": "rules for the placing on the market of products with digital elements to ensure the cybersecurity of such products; ",
            "(b)": "essential requirements for the design, development and production of products with digital elements, and obligations for economic operators in relation to these products with respect to cybersecurity;"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My html:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Commission<br></th>
            <th>Parliament</th>
            <th>Council</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <template x-for="(chapter, number) in file.articles">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <h3 x-text="number + ': ' + chapter.title"></h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <template x-for="(article, number) in chapter.articles">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <h4 x-text="number + ': ' + article.title"></h4>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <template x-for="(paragraph, nb_paragraph) in article.paragraphs">
                    <tr>
                        <td x-text="nb_paragraph"></td>
                        <td x-text="paragraph"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </template>
</table>
```

Comment: A `template` can only have a singular root. You'll have to find a way to make your template fit in one of the roots...

Comment: did you tried to flat this object ?

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation ( and many others ), you can take advantage of the CSS `display` property along with the `contents` value.

You can find documentation on this specific one [here](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-display/#valdef-display-contents) or [here](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/01/29/vanishing-boxes-with-display-contents/)

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.10.5/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<script>
  fileJSON = {
  "articles": {
    "CHAPTER I": {
      "title": "GENERAL PROVISIONS",
      "articles": {
        "Article 1": {
          "title": "Subject matter",
          "paragraphs": {
            "p_1": "This Regulation lays down:",
            "(a)": "rules for the placing on the market of products with digital elements to ensure the cybersecurity of such products; ",
            "(b)": "essential requirements for the design, development and production of products with digital elements, and obligations for economic operators in relation to these products with respect to cybersecurity;"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
<table x-data="{file: fileJSON}">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Commission<br></th>
            <th>Parliament</th>
            <th>Council</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <template x-for="(chapter, number) in file.articles">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <h3 x-text="number + ': ' + chapter.title"></h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <template x-for="(article, number) in chapter.articles">
                <div style="display: contents">
                  <tr>
                      <td colspan="100%">
                          <h4 x-text="number + ': ' + article.title"></h4>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <template x-for="(paragraph, nb_paragraph) in article.paragraphs">
                      <tr>
                          <td x-text="nb_paragraph"></td>
                          <td x-text="paragraph"></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                      </tr>
                  </template>
              </div>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </template>
</table>
```